# How many biological children does Odin have in MCU canon?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe

In Norse mythology Odin had five biological sons, and an unspecified number of daughters, by various mothers.

How many biological children did the MCU version - based on, but differing substantially from his inspiring figure - have in franchise canon, and what were their names?

If there are any beyond Thor and his sister, who are they, and in which material is their relationship to Odin confirmed?

Answer (score 2):

At this point we have no specific knowledge of any other *children of Odin*, other than those you've already mentioned.

Odin had [Hela](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Hela) with an unspecified mother, [Thor](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Thor) with [Frigga](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Frigga) and adopted [Loki](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Loki).

[image]

Comment: Now, if you were asking about the Marvel *comics*, we'd have a bunch more kids to mention; Aldrif Odinsdottir (AKA Angela), Vidar, Balder, etc.